# How would I reset my MediaPlayer in Android Studio 2.2.3?

Tags: android-studio

So I am trying to make a button that plays a sound, at one point it asked me something about opening the sound file I want on my computer, I did not really see it and click on my PC, so every time I run my app the file gets played on my PC and the app never gets launched, anyone know how I would reset that? (Tried a new project, restarted.)

Here is some of my code:
MainActivity.java

```
package tech.mitchs.scarcesoundboard;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button bt;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Hey_Guys);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.diwali);

    Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I'm done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });
        }
    });

    Button pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    });
}
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/play" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pause" />
```

This worked best for me, including playing and pausing of media that is attached.

Comment: The problem is everytime I hit run, it resets all my Rs.
"Error:Error: 'H' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore"

https://mitchs.tech/i/858c1.png
I need to reset it somehow.

Comment: Please define the resource name in lowercase. That's android naming convention you are encountering as error. You have defined `R.raw.Hey_Guys`, change it to `R.raw.hey_guys`.

Comment: Please mark as correct answer if your problem is solved. Thanks! :)